# How to Renew a Revoked Certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate

I have just finished my first app and I want to submit it to the iTunes store. In getting ready I read a tutorial that said I should first clean up all certificates and provisioning profiles.  So, as per this guys instructions, I revoked my certificate.

Now, I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to get it back.  I've found an apparently out of date articles by Apple ([TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html)) which no longer applies to my version of Xcode (4.3.2). In the Certificates section of the Provisioning Portal I can see no way to renew my certificate, or create a new one.  I even called Apple's support and the nice gal was sweet but in the end was not able to help me and told me she was not technical support and I would need to ask my questions in the various help-forums.

How to renew my cert? Or create a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two certificates: one is for the development cert and another one is the distribution certificate.

If they are expired or you revoked them.  You need to using key chain from your apple computer to generate the certificate requests.

Go to your apple computer, Open Application->utilities->keychain Access
Keychain Access->certificate Assantance->Request a certificate from a certificate authority 
Fill in your email address and name, pick Save to disk

You need to generate two certificate for both the development certificate and the distribution certificate

Then:

You login to your provisioning portal. 
Click the certificate manual on your left side
There two certificates: one is for the development cert and another one is the distribution certificate.
You request a new certificate from the portal, upload your certificate request you generated earlier.

You should be able to get your new certificates.  You download these two certificates on to your computer, and double click the certificates to install them into your keychain.

Please let me know if you have problems to get your new certificate.